# join sql query based on value of another table (in one query)

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say that I have two tables A and B where

A is table countries with columns id, name, created, modified

that contains a bunch of countries

And B is table users with columns id, first_name, last_name, email, country_id, created, modified

that contains a bunch of users linked to countries via foreign key *country_id*

What is the most efficient query to get all the countries that don't have a user with email address "myemail@test.com" associated to it?

I tried something like the following but that didn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.*
FROM
    countries c
LEFT JOIN
    users u ON u.country_id = c.id
WHERE
    u.email <> 'myemail@test.com'
```

Thanks for any help

**NOTE** I also tried putting the condition on the email column in the ON clause that didn't work either

Answer (score 3):

A `left join` is fine, you just need to set it up correctly:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM countries c LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.country_id = c.id AND u.email = 'myemail@test.com'
WHERE u.country_id IS NULL;
```

In terms of performance, this should be pretty similar to `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` (although I do not recommend the latter because it has different behavior when there are `NULL` values).

Answer (score 0):

When you say "that don't have a user with email address "myemail@test.com"",
 do you mean no email address -or- not that exact email address?

**Updated**

Then this should do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM countries c
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.country_id = c.id and u.email = 'myemail@test.com'
WHERE u.country_id is null
```

Which I believe is what Gordon already had.

**Updated Again**

In that case, try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM countries c
INNER JOIN users u ON u.country_id = c.id and ISNULL(u.email, '') = ''
```

This looks for Null or Empty String email adresses all others are excluded from the join and therefore from the result set.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, same as @Gordon

Comment: My bad, you said: NOT that exact address - New Solution on the way.

Comment: @user765368 , One of the two queries above should be the one.  But I'm still not sure about your question. It sounds like you're saying (and Gordon interpreted this way too) that everybody in every country is supposed to have the same email address - show me a list of countries where there is at least one user who doesn't have the same address as the rest of the world.  Is that correct?